# ZF2 Serialize data from Instagram API

Tags: php, api, serialization, zend-framework2, instagram

Since Instagram API has a limitation of request per hour (not sure how many). Would you advise to use serialize for storing the data from instagram feed? If not, what else would you advise?

If Yes, I'm not sure about the structure and where should i wrote my code for the serialize part.

Until now i've been using the instagram code inside my footer (layout.phtml).

Should i create a module just for storing those data and reloading the data once a day? If you don't advise that solution, what else could i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stand-up a memcached server and proxy your API requests through that. You can easily configure the TTL of the cache to balance the freshness of data with your API limitations. This all depends on the cardinality of unique API requests though. If you are making a lot of identical requests to Instagram, this would be an ideal setup.

Storage in memcached would be trivial if you are using PHP as you can write objects directly (no explicit serialization required):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php

You would use the API request string directly or a hashed version of it as the key for the memcached entry containing the Instagram API response object.

Comment: Okay i'll check this out.

So serialize is not a good option you think?

Comment: @Brieuc - Serialization is required to store in memcached or similar system, but PHP does that for you implicitly when you use the set() method as described in the link above.